# Request data format for category field update

Tags: node.js, podio

I am using the podio-js package in a project designed to handle our invoicing. I am currently facing a problem in my attempts to update an item's category type field.

Here is the code I am currently running with:

```
const url = `/item/${item_id}/value/${field_id}`;

// newOptionId is the id of the option I want to switch to

const requestData = JSON.stringify({[field_id]: newOptionId});

const responseData = await this.podio.request('PUT', url, requestData);
```

I tried several other formats as described here: https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/add-new-item-22362, but every time I get the same result, it unselects the current selected option and leaves my category type field with no selected option.

Please provide me with the correct requestData format as  I think the problem is coming from there.

Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking.

Comment: I need to now how to update a category type field in my invoice item whose purpose is to notify the current status of the invoicing process. The options of the targeted field labeled 'satus' are: unsent, sent, viewed, paid

Answer (score 0):

The request format {value: your_id} is not supported anymore, it worked for me using this.podio.request('PUT', url, [myId]) to update a category field.

@Podio team: it would be cool to update and complete your documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 slightly different ways of setting value to a field.
1. One when creating new item [Podio: create item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/add-new-item-22362)
2. Another one when updating whole item [Podio: update item](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-22363). This includes for example reverting to specific revision or setting each and every field including meta-fields like files, reminders, recurrences, etc.
3. Yet another one is updating item value [Podio: update item value](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-values-22366), which is updating whole item but only fields. So, it only accepts content that is inside `fields` parameter for methods #1 and #2 above.
4. And one more is for updating item field values [Podio: update item field values](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-field-values-22367). This one expects values for single field and only content of `fields['field_id']` from methods #1 and #2 should be passed here.

Each way requires different format for `value` and uses different `url`.
I've updated documentation to include 2 cURLs examples for last 2 methods to make it clear, but will be happy to include additional explanations if you provide them.